# Vue select box, pre-select with one option and fill options with array from different axios call

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple select that i currently fill with one option from an axios response object. The issue is that the `currentName` value comes from an initial call and I want this to be the "selected" option at the time of that call. however, when I click the select and open up the options, I want to actually fill the available options with a different array of values from a new axios call, which is filling the `selectOptions` array.

How can I fill the selected option with `currentName` but still allow `selectOptions` to be the selectable options when I trigger the select? Assuming I have an onClick on the select that makes my 2nd axios call and populates `selectOptions`

```
<select class="firstLastNames linkBox">
  <option>{{currentName}}</option>
</select>

...

return {
  currentName: '',
  selectOptions: []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `v-for` and `v-model` to do what you want.
First you have to populate the select options from your `selectOptions` array.
In the html you could wright this:

```
<select class="firstLastNames linkBox" v-model="currentName">
  <option v-for="option in selectOptions" :value="option.id">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
```

And in the `selectOptions` array you could have an array of objects like:

```
return {
    currentName: "",
    selectOptions: [
        {id: 0, text: "Name one"},
        {id: 1, text: "Name two"}
    ]
}
```

That way your `selectOption` are the options the user can select from and the `currentName` the selected value from the options.

The values you pass in the `id` are going to be the values kept in `currentName` as you pass here `:value="option.id"`

So, if the user selects "Name one" the `currentName` value would be `0`.
Or if the user selects "Name two" the `currentName` value would be `1`.

Comment: I think this got it, thanks so much! I was messed up on the v-model portion especially

Comment: Get a time to read the documentation from VueJS website, they are very usefull and understandable for beginners. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html